# Use linq query to find next matching record (Alarms with state)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Datatable filled with records about a PLC alarm state changed (Raised = ON,Solved = OFF). Each record contains the Date,Hour,Zone,AlarmCode,AlarmState('O'|'C').

How can i use linq,given the list of 'O'(ON), to find the "nearest" next corresponding 'C'(OFF) state (obv with the same Zone and AlarmCode)? 
Also it would be good to provide the duration and the alarms still opened('O' Without 'C') or the alarms closed without opening(Because of the 'O' is not on the current interval selected).

Here i posted the code that i'm using right now (very basic)

```
 private void CalculateAlarms()
       {

            DataTable dtOn, dtOff;
            DateTime dON, dOFF;

            dtOn = dtAlr.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("STATE").Equals("O")).CopyToDataTable(); //ALREADY ORDERED BY DATE,HOUR
            dtOff = dtAlr.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("STATE").Equals("C")).CopyToDataTable(); //ALREADY ORDERED BY DATE,HOUR

            dtOn.Columns.Add("Min", typeof(TimeSpan));
            dtOn.Columns.Add("HourOff", typeof(DateTime));

            foreach (DataRow rowON in dtOn.Rows)
            {
                dON = rowON["DATETIMEALR"];

                foreach (DataRow rowOff in dtOff.Rows)
                {
                    dOFF = rowOFF["DATETIMEALR"];
                    if (rowON["ALRCOD"].Equals(rowOff["ALRCOD"]) && rowON["ALRZONE"].Equals(rowOff["ALRZONE"]) && DateTime.Compare(dON, dOFF) <= 0)
                    {
                        rowON["HourOff"] = dOFF;
                        rowON["Min"] = dOFF.Subtract(dON);
                        dtOff.Rows.Remove(rowOff);
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }
            DataTable toCopy;

            toCopy = dtOn.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.IsNull("HourOff"));

            DataTable OnWithoutOFF = toCopy.Any() ? toCopy.CopyToDataTable() : new DataTable();

            toCopy = dtOn.AsEnumerable().Where(x => !x.IsNull("HourOff"));
            dtOn = toCopy.Any() ? toCopy.CopyToDataTable() : new DataTable();

            // So here i have OnWithoutOFF => Alarms opened but not closed , dtOn => Alarms opened and closed , dtOff => Alarms closed but not opened 


        }
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve the issue and what problems did you run into?

Comment: Why do you have so many differing terms for the same thing? ("Raised", "ON", "O" and "Solved", "OFF", "C")

Comment: `First` can be used to find the next row (assuming they are in chronological order) that matches a condition (i.e. `FirstOrDefault(ro => DateTime.Compare(dON, ro["DATETIMEALR"]) <= 0 && rowON["ALRCOD"] == ro["ALRCOD"] && rowON["ALRZONE"] == ro["ALRZONE"])`).

Comment: @Cray i'm not facing any problem,i only want to improve my code (if possible) since i dont want it to be slow..